# Installing ma2c with python on Win7, cmd not recognizing ma2c

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, cmd

I'm installing the program [MA2C](http://liulab.dfci.harvard.edu/MA2C/MA2C.htm) with Python (v 2.7). I've added Python and ma2c directories to PATH, and Python directories to PYTHONPATH (including site-packages, which does contain MA2C) in environmental variables (system variables), but still get the error message that  `'ma2c' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` when I run ma2c example.tag in cmd.exe.

I've searched for similar problems with other Python programs but have so far come up empty. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the ma2c file, append .py, and simply type "ma2c.py" instead of "ma2c" in cmd to get the program running.